# How to find cutoff values in multinomial regression?

Tags: logistic, multinomial-distribution, latent-class

**Updated**

I have a data set with five continuous variables measuring an index in a population. For finding underlying classifications in the population based on the five observed variables,
I did a latent profiles analysis (LPA) for two and three categories model using all five variables.The task is to find cutoff values for each variable in order to classify new observations without doing the whole procedure.

Then I used produced categorization from LPA to find relative weights of each of the five variables using logistic (for two-category solution) and multinomial (for three-category solution) regression.That was for finding the relative contribution of each variable to the classification.Next step was to find cutoff values for each variable for future use.

For finding cutoff values for each variable, I could find cutoff for each variable in two-category solution by using logistic regression and setting the regression equation equal to 0.5 and then finding corresponding value of the variable.In other words,I used predicted categorization by LPA as a criterion (DV) for each variable in logistic regression.I didn't use ROC because it didn't give me reasonable results.

My question is, how to do the same thing for three-category solution? I tried multinomial regression but I didn't came up with a solution. with three categories I need to have two cutoff values in order to define category boundaries for each variable.

Or simply, how to determine cutoff values for a variable based on a predefined categorizes to match with the categories?

Comment: You didn't explain how information-losing cutoffs would help.  And note that if a cutoff for a variable exists it must be a function of the values of the other variables.

Comment: @FrankHarrell the information-losing due to using single predictor is not of my concern.I mentioned that in case if some one said that it's better to use all five variables.What do mean that cutoff for one variable should be a function of other four variables as well? in addition to categorical DV?

Comment: Why are you doing all this? What are you trying to find out? This seems a very complex procedure full of assumptions.

Comment: @PeterFlom I assumed that we have a latent categorical variable that divides the sample into different groups.Then we need to find cutoff values for each category in order to categorize future data without doing the same procedure.

Comment: What I was referring to is that if there is any place for making cutoffs, the cutoff must be made on the predicted $Y$, e.g., predicted $Prob[Y=1]$.  Then solve for which values of $X$ put you in the high group of predictions.  You will find that this induces a cutoff for $X_{1}$ that is dependent on the continuous value of $X_{2}$.  By the way why the need to _categorize_ future data?

Comment: @FrankHarrell I meant categorizing subjects into two or three categories based on their scores in five variables. These five variables will be used for categorizing subjects into two groups ( vulnerable or not) or three groups (having great difficulty/mild difficulty/ without difficulties).I want to find cutoff values for each of the five variables for two and three category solution.Subject's scores will be compared to cutoffs for determining the relevant category.

Comment: That is ill-defined and you will find that the categorizations are quite arbitrary and non-reproducible.  Probabilities of category membership will allow you to see which subjects are uncategorizable.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thanks.The way I came across with is using multinomial regression for each variable twice.First setting the last category as reference, by setting `ln[P(Class=2)/P(Class=3)]` equal to 0 I can find corresponding score for boundary between second and third category. Then by setting the second category as reference I can find boundary between the first and second category by setting `ln[P(Class=1)/P(Class=2)]` equal to 0.

Comment: Why you would ever want to do this is beyond my understanding.

Comment: @FrankHarrell as I said, via LPA I found classes and then I needed to find cutoff values for each variable to match this classification.I couldn't use descriptive stats because for each class I had full range of value (i.e. each variable ranges 0-10) then came up with that method.The reason is to predict classes via individual variables as well.

Comment: The motive is still unclear.  What is the ultimate goal of the exercise?  What does 'found classes' mean?  What is the rawest form of the data?

Comment: @FrankHarrell those five variables are measures of child development and three classes represent three stages of child development.The developers of tool want to know cutoffs for categories in each variable to see what range of values determine classes.Each variable takes values 0-10 and because classes are determined by all five variables, each category contains values 0-10 for variables So I couldn't use simple descriptive stat to find cutoffs.Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: The developers are not going about this the right way.  Such cutoffs do not exist.  They are arbitrary impositions on the data.  If the stages of development truly have all-or-nothing demarkations, you can use an ordinal or polytomus logistic model to estimate probabilities of developmental category membership.  Besides thinking about that please give us the formal definitions of the stages.

Comment: @FrankHarrell The cutoffs are not necessarily arbitrary impositions on the data rather there should be acceptable reason for setting cutoffs. In the way I'm gonna do, I'm doing a reverse procedure indeed, by first extracting classes and the finding cutoffs. The way I did was using ordinal regression for each variable as IV and classes as DV. Then by setting log-odds equal to zero I found cutoff.Class 1 represents kids experiencing great difficulty,class 2 represents kids experiencing difficulty and class 3 represents kids who developed appropriately.

Comment: That is nonsensical.  You are torturing the data to find cutoffs that don't exist.  Unless you have strong subject matter information (which you apparently don't), using the data to find such cutoffs is completely arbitrary.  A test of your approach is to split the data into to halves and give another analyst half the data telling her that "cutoffs must be chosen" and see if she finds the same cutoffs as you with no more information.  BTW to even attempt what you are doing requires an enormous sample size.  How many subjects do you have in each stage?  And please answer my earlier questions.

Comment: @FrankHarrell As I have about 82000 subject, I split the data set into two halves and ran the analysis on both. I got the same results which I already got using the whole sample.As for checking, I extracted the classes in one half and tried to cutoffs in another half. I came up with almost the same values (differences were in third decimal).
If with "earlier questions" you mean the definition, those I told you before are all know.

Comment: You need to know more about the problem than that to be able to find the best analytical method.  You have an excellent sample size but the strategy is flawed.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I can send you more information directly to have your advice.Is it fine if email you?

Comment: Very sorry I'm swamped right now; fine to discuss in general on this site if you want.  Of crucial interest is how the ultimate research question got translated into discrete development stages and how this got translated to the need for cutoffs.